# directx fails to build windows 8

Tags: c++, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

Following this example:

http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=111-1-2

I entered the first big set of code to run to get a basic window (code is in link).
After attempting to build, I get the following errors:

- Error    1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol **imp**_CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "void __cdecl Microsoft::WRL::Details::CheckForDuplicateEntries >(struct Microsoft::WRL::Details::CreatorMap const * *,struct Microsoft::WRL::Details::CreatorMap const * *,class )" (??$CheckForDuplicateEntries@V@@@Details@WRL@Microsoft@@YAXPAPBUCreatorMap@012@0V@@@Z)   c:\Users\Paul Lewis 2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DxGame\DxGame\vccorlibd.lib(init.obj)
- Error    2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   c:\Users\Foobar 2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DxGame\Debug\DxGame\DxGame.exe  1

Does anyone know what is going on?

**UPDATE**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229582.aspx yields the same errors.

**I'm using Windows 8 Pro (64) and VS2012 Ultimate**

Comment: Are you getting this error while trying to build Debug, Release or both?

Comment: @IronMensan Debug. Someone told me to try Release, and now it works. Still wondering why Debug doesn't work even though DX11 is built into VS2012

Comment: Make sure your Debug configuration is set to use the debug C runtime.  Mixing the Debug DirectX with the Release runtime could cause this error.

Comment: @IronMensan do you know how to set it up to work in Debug mode?